# NEXJS stripe v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Missing value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Missing value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string.

I'm getting this error in next JS when trying to use stripe pre-built checkout.

.env.local
(full key replaced with ..... for stackoverflow)

```
NEXT_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=pk_test_51Jl......
```

in function call

```
 const stripe = await loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);
```

if I was to put the Publishable key directly in it works but from the env its not working for
some reason

for example this would work

```
  const stripe = await loadStripe(`pk_test_51Jl...`);
```

I have the example below also and it didn't work.

```
const stripe = await loadStripe(`${process.env.NEXT_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`);
```

Comment: If you're trying to use it on the client (browser), the ENV needs to be prefixed with [NEXT_PUBLIC_](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Missing value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string. Only while deployed to vercel but working fine on local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757467/1870780)?

Answer (score 0):

what I think is your key should be in quotation marks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).